how to parameterize the in Scenario outline when reading csv files using "read"
I have the below scenario outline to read the file based on the environment.
Scenario Outline:
Given
When
Then
Examples:
| read ('testdata-SIT'.csv) |
I want to parameterize the 'testdata-<env>'.csv based on the environment in which the test is running
I tried the below by passing the env variable from config.js file.

| read ('testdata'+env+'.csv') |  - didnt work

*def filename = 'testdata'+env+'.csv'
  | read(filename) | - didnt work



In the above 2 cases, file was not replaced properly so file not found error.
Please suggest the right way of doing. Thanks!

Yes, the dynamic version of the Scenario Outline is evaluated before karate-config.js. The "normal flow" (including Background if applicable) for each "row" of data has to call karate-config.js. Calling it one extra time "before all rows" will cause problems, and each Scenario will not start from a "clean slate".
The @setup tag was introduced to solve the need to set up data before the dynamic  outline. So you can do this:
Feature:
@setup
Scenario:
  * def data = read(filename)

Scenario Outline:
  * print __row

  Examples:
  | karate.setup().data |

